# Box-shadow works on some elements, not others?

Tags: html, css

I hate posting a question like this but I'm literally going insane.  I have some css to define a box shadow.  It was working fine and then I happened to notice it isn't working on my menu panels all of a sudden.  It works on literally every element on the page, but the menu panel.

Here's the .shadow class css

```
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
}
```

Here's the menu panel css

```
.menu-panel {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 350px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Here's the menu-button css, which is the button that opens the panel. The shadow works fine on it.

```
.menu-button-clipped {
  position: absolute;
  background:url(../images/menu-icon-64.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 28px 28px;
  background-position: 18px 18px;
  /*background-color: rgba(43, 140, 236, 1.0);*/
  background-color: #F62A2A;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Here's the javascript that builds the HTML templates with Mustache.

```
  var menuButtonTemplate = '<div id={{ menuButtonID }} class="menu-toggle menu-button-clipped shadow"></div>';
  var menuPanelTemplate = '<div id={{ menuPanelID }} class="shadow menu-panel" ><h1>Settings</h1>' +
    '<table class="radio-button-group"><thead><tr><th colspan="2">Graph Options</th></tr></thead><tbody>' +
    '<tr class="graph-toggle" data-name={{ graphName }} ><td>Activate</td><td class="cell activate"><div class=radio-button-off></div></td></tr>' +
    '<tr class="graph-toggle" data-name={{ graphName }} ><td>Deactivate</td><td class="cell deactivate"><div class=radio-button-on></div></td></tr>' +
    '</tbody></table>' +
    '<table class="radio-button-group"><thead><tr><th colspan="2">Axis Options</th></tr></thead><tbody>' +
    '<tr class="graph-toggle" data-name={{ graphName }} ><td>Link</td><td class="cell link_axis"><div class={{ linkedState }}></div></td></tr>' +
    '<tr class="graph-toggle" data-name={{ graphName }} ><td>Un-link</td><td class="cell unlink_axis"><div class={{ unlinkedState }}></div></td></tr>' +
    '</tbody></table>' +
    '<table class="radio-button-group"><thead><tr><th colspan="2">Trace Options</th></tr></thead><tbody>' +
    '<tr class="graph-toggle" data-name={{ graphName }} ><td>Show Traceline</td><td class="cell trace_lines"><div class=radio-button-off></div></td></tr>' +
    '<tr class="graph-toggle" data-name={{ graphName }} ><td>Hide Traceline</td><td class="cell no_trace_lines"><div class=radio-button-on></div></td></tr>' +
    '</tbody></table>' +
    '</div>';

  $('#' + menuButtonID).css({ zIndex: '200', marginLeft: '-26px'});
  $('#' + menuButtonID).css('marginTop', yOffset - 26);
  $('#' + menuPanelID).css({ zIndex: '150', marginLeft: '0px'});
  $('#' + menuPanelID).css('marginTop', yOffset);
  $('#' + menuPanelID).css('height', height);
```

And to make things easier, here's what the plain old HTML would look like without anything in the panel

```
<div class="menu-toggle menu-button-clipped shadow"></div>
<div class="shadow menu-panel"><some heading and table stuff></div>
```

The shadow works on the menu-button div, but it doesn't show up for the panel.  When I inspect the source code in safari, it is showing the box-shadow as a css property for the panel...it's just not actually rendering it.  Can someone tell me if I'm making an obviously stupid mistake here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fnsn1uww/ you can see the panel doesn't have a shadow

Comment: Well of course not, you have `visibility : hidden`

Comment: Ah, yes. That's toggled with javascript. Okay, so I can't replicate the issue with a jsFiddle apparently.

Comment: What's the actual functionality here? The panel is not visible hence no shadow, remove the visibility:hidden and it shows a shadow. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ordanj are you certain your javascript is removing the `visibility:hidden`? In your sample code in the question you never remove `visibility:hidden`

Comment: @ordanj, Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/fnsn1uww/4/

Comment: Yes, because the panel opens over an image so it is easy to see that it's there.  I was hoping the issue was related to my absolute positioning or something.  Everything worked fine until I started messing with LESS

Comment: Try creating a fiddle based on your rendered CSS/HTML to reproduce the issue. Without that it's just wild shots in the dark

Comment: @thePav that is a better way to toggle the panel, but unfortunately that's not my problem.  Panel opens fine. For some reason the shadow is just not displaying for the panel.

Comment: @JonathanCrowe I'll keep working on that.

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate the problem, but I did find that `box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #888;` works while `box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` does not